# match one or more in regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex like this:

`[ABC]\d\d\d`

which matches strings like `B434` or `A919` but does not match strings like `B434-3` or `B232-8`

I've tried modifying the regex to: `[ABC]\d\d\d(-\d)*`, however, for what I'm doing I need to do this without a match group. Is this possible to do?

**Question**

Is it possible to have a regex that matches (for example) `B434` as well as `B341-3` without match groups?

Comment: If you want to match the dash digit part only once, you could use an optional non capturing group `[ABC]\d\d\d(?:-\d)?`

Comment: Please add the code you have trouble with to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need:

`[ABC]\d\d\d(?:-\d)?`

the **?:** will make it a Non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

We could also use the pattern below:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val setPattern: Regex = """[A-Z\-0-9]""".r
```

The link gives explanation about the patterns - https://regexr.com/